# Cannot read SAS View using different libname other than what was used to create the view

Tags: view, sas

I created a view in SAS to read multiple dataset. I can read data from this view only if I give same libname that was used to create the view.

```
libname test "c:\temp";
data test.one; x=1; run; 
data test.two; x=2; run;
data test.three; x=3; 
run;proc sql ; 
create view test.master as     
   select * from test.one     union   
   select * from test.two     union
   select * from test.three; 
quit;  
data test;
    set test.master; 
run;
```

The above code runs fine but when I open a new sas session and use different 
libname as below I get error:

```
libname new "c:\temp";
data test; 
    set new.master;
run; 
ERROR: Libref TEST is not assigned.
ERROR: Libref TEST is not assigned.
ERROR: Libref TEST is not assigned. 
ERROR: SQL View TEST.PANEL2 could not be processed because at least one of the data sets, or views, referenced directly (or 
   indirectly) by it could not be located, or opened successfully.
```

Please Advise

Comment: How would SAS know that you wanted NEW.one instead of TEST.one?

Comment: The view was read fine, the view execution failed because prerequisite conditions were wrong (I.e. the required accessors (libnames) or constructs (tables and columns therein) were not defined or present)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that I think that is good idea, but if you do want to do that then you could embed the libname definition into the view with the `using` clause.  Put the path into the view name also and you don't even ever have to create the libref `test` at all.

```
proc sql ; 
create view 'C:\temp\master' as     
   select * from test.one     union   
   select * from test.two     union
   select * from test.three
   using libname test 'C:\temp' 
; 
quit;
```

Now you are not required to use the same libref, but note that you **are** required to use the same physical location.

Answer (score 1):

**Create View**

A `create view` creates the instructions to use when the view is accessed for processing.  The `select` statement is **checked for syntax**, but **not checked regarding data sources**.  Thus, the view construct contains the unverified librefs, table names, and the column names it will need during processing.

You can create a view even when the session has no active libnames (see Example below).  View creation is akin to writing and saving a SAS program, but not submitting it right away.

**Libname and libref**

The `libname` statement creates a library reference, or libref for short. From documentation (my bold):

> **LIBNAME Statement**
>
> Associates or disassociates a SAS library with a **libref** (a shortcut name), clears one or all librefs, lists the characteristics of a SAS library, concatenates SAS libraries, or concatenates SAS catalogs.

The term `libname` is used in discussion when identifying an instance of a libref, but sometimes the libname is used when the more technically precise term **libref** is meant.    The typical experience for SAS users is that a libname associates to a single folder or directory.

**View use (execution)**

When the view is accessed the processing instructions are executed, using the current state of the SAS session, with respect to the active librefs, in order to create the result set.

This is a good thing!

- In an ad-hoc environment a view can be passed amongst users and they can decide which library the **libref** points to.
- In a production environment the SAS admin would ensure the libref points to the proper and current library.
- In order to use a view in the same session state it was when it was created, the current and future sessions must have the same librefs and necessary library contents.
- If a view fails for libnames reasons, simply create the needed libnames pointing to the proper libraries.

**Example**

Richard the view maker

```
libname shazaam; * now there is no shazaam ! ;
proc sql;
  create view sasuser.lightning as
  select * from shazaam.powersource
  where situation='danger'
  and pigs='fly'
  and
  ;
```

Richard sends his `sasuser.lightning` view (`*.sas7bvew`) to Bob and Jane.

Bob's session

```
libname shazaam 'c:\super-heroes\shaz\sasdata';

proc sql;    
  select * from sasuser.lightning;

--- FAILS because shazaam.powersource exists but powersource does not have column `pigs`.
```

Jane's session

```
libname shazaam 'c:\heroes\shazaam_v2\sasdata'

proc sql;    
  select * from sasuser.lightning;

--- WORKS because in Jane's '_v2' data shazaam.powersource exists and column `pigs` is present
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the 'test' in the view query, not the `libname`. Remember, the view is only run when you try and access it.

So if the library exists the view can run, but since the `test` library doesn't exist, it's trying to read from library that doesn't exist.

Here's an example of your 'view' that does work:

```
libname test "/folders/myfolders/Temp";

proc sql ; 
create view test.master as     
   select * from sashelp.cars (obs=4)     union   
   select * from sashelp.cars (firstobs=10 obs=14)     union
   select * from sashelp.cars (firstobs=30 obs=34); 
quit;  


data test;
    set test.master; 
run;

libname test ;

libname new "/folders/myfolders/Temp";

data test2; 
    set new.master;
run;
```

@Tom has provided a workaround.